# Add objects to LRUCache

Tags: android, caching, android-lru-cache

I want to cache objects of custom claas, which implements serializable using LRUCache in android. It is possible? If yes, how can I proceed to do the same?

Comment: you don't use SQLite instead?

Comment: Have you studied butmapFun sample for caching Bitmap objects?: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Answer (score 1):

LruCache has the syntax of that of a Map i.e LruCache key value pair. I can't see any reason why you can't store objects of Custom class in it. It will behave like a Map. On the other hand LruCache is generally used to cache bitmaps.

Comment: Finally I succeed in adding object in disk cache. I was directly writing the serialized object into cache; it was storing also; but when application restarts, that object was getting cleared from cache. So I wrote that object in file using ObjectOutputStream and it worked!